# Сохранение сессии через AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, сессия

Допустим у нас есть 2 файла:

1ий:

```
<div id="put" onclick="put()">Нажимаем</div>
<div id="show"></div>
<?php 
   session_start();
   print_r($_SESSION);
?>

<script>
    function put(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"testtestSessia.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:{text: 'hilay'},
            success:function(data){
              $('#show').html(data);
          }
        });
    }
</script>
```

2ой - `testtestSessia.php` Он загружается через AJAX в div:

```
<?php
    $nnn=$_POST['text'];
    $_SESSION['nnn']=$nnn;
    print_r($_SESSION);
```

Задача в следующем - нужно чтобы через ajax-скрипт в сессию записалось значение. После этого, как я понимаю, при перезагрузке страницы я хочу использовать его уже без загрузки скрипта. Но `print_r($_SESSION);` выводит пустой массив.

В чем моя ошибка? Почему сессия не сохраняется?

Comment: а в `testtestSessia` кто будет писать `session_start();`, Пушкин? ))

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: Да, просто продолжи предыдущую сессию.